# AUTHENTICATE failed: Oauth2 Node Office 365 Microsoft

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, office365, imap

I have following code which is supposed to open a connection to a Microsoft Exchange server via IMAP and read Emails.

```
{
  user: '****',
  password: '****'
  xoauth2= Buffer.from([`user=*****`, `auth=Bearer **MyToken**`, '', ''].join('\x01'), 'utf-8').toString('base64'),
  host: 'outlook.office365.com',
  port: 993,
  tls: true,
  autotls: 'always',
  tlsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false, servername: 'outlook.office365.com' },
  socketTimeout: 10000,
  keepalive: { interval: 30000, idleInterval: 300000, forceNoop: false },
  debug: false
}
```

This is how I get Token

```
const msal = require('@azure/msal-node');
const config = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "ClientID",
        // authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/",
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/Tenant",
        clientSecret: "ClientSecret"
    }
};
// Create msal application object
const cca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(config);

// With client credentials flows permissions need to be granted in the portal by a tenant administrator.
// The scope is always in the format "<resource>/.default"
const clientCredentialRequest = {
    scopes: ["https://outlook.office365.com/.default"], // replace with your resource
    // scopes: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default","https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All"]
};

const getToken = async () => {
    return cca.acquireTokenByClientCredential(clientCredentialRequest);
}

module.exports={
    getToken
}
```

This is granted privileges on Azure

[image]

But finally I have this error

```
[connection] Connected to host
<= '* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [TQBSADIAUAAyADYANABDAEEAMAAxADMAMwAuAEYAUgBBAFAAMgA2ADQALgBQAFIATwBEAC4ATwBVAFQATABPAE8ASwAuAEMATwBNAA==]'
=> 'A0 CAPABILITY'
<= '* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+'
<= 'A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.'
=> 'A1 AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 dXNlchCYU9HVXRkVEZTZVhCTWNWaHpja3RNYVVsTWVYcDRlR2ROUWpSVVVUazRNVlpTTmtock1YTWlMQ0poYkdjaU9pSlNVekkxTmlJc0luZzFkQ0k2***=='
<= 'A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.'
Error: AUTHENTICATE failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

That error usually indicates that you haven't registered the service principal or granted explicit access to the Mailbox this is at the bottom of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth#register-service-principals-in-exchange

IMAP App permissions work differently from the Graph App permission in the Graph when you have App permission you get access to everybody's mailbox in the tenant by default. With the IMAP permission you don't and every mailbox that you need to access will need to have permission explicitly granted via Add-Mailbox (and you need to wait 15-60 minutes for those permissions to take affect)